# call a shell script from another shell script via sudo - environment variables?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, sudo

I'm calling bash script B from script A. In script A (parent script) I am exporting some variables. I would like to use these variables in script B (subscript), but the variable values are not being passed on from script A to script B. Is there a way to access the variable values from script B?

```
#!/bin/bash
# script_A.sh
export VAR="value"
enter code here
sudo -u user ./script_B.sh

#!/bin/bash
# script_B.sh
echo $VAR    # this prints nothing
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @geekosaur mentioned, `sudo` resets the environment for security reasons.
To preserve the environment pass `-E` switch to `sudo`.

from the `sudo` manpage:

> `-E`
>
> The `-E` (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing
>                      environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the `-E` option is specified and the user does not have
>                      permission to preserve the environment.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not with the shell script, but that for security reasons `sudo` sanitizes the environment it passes to the program it runs.  See `man sudoers` for details, and `/etc/sudoers` on your system for what (if any) environment variables it will preserve.

Comment: geekosaur is right. adding the -E file to the sudo command will preserve the environment and pass it to the subscript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only a specific set of variables (rather than all of them) for reasons of security or simplicity, you can simply **assign them as part of the `sudo` command**:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$foo"
$ unset foo
$ foo=bar ./test.sh
bar
$ sudo foo=bar ./test.sh
bar
```